# Update parent table with strongest status of child table using MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Working with two tables, one-to-many relationship, I need to update the parent table with the strongest status of all of its child entries. Based on the entries in Table2, the outcome of Table1 should be like this:

```
                  +-----------------------+    +-----------------------+
                  | Table1                |    | Table2                |
                  +-----------------------+    +-----------------------+
                  | table1_id  |status1   |    | table1_id  |status2   |
                  +-----------------------+    +-----------------------+
                  |0           |1         |    |0           |1         |
                  |1           |0         |    |0           |1         |
                  |2           |2         |    |1           |0         |
                  |3           |0         |    |1           |2         |
                  +-----------------------+    |2           |1         |
                                               |2           |2         |
                                               |3           |1         |
                                               |3           |0         |
                                               +-----------------------+
```

Where 0 is strongest, and 1 is weakest, 2 is middle.

I've thought about using `MIN()` or `MAX()` or even multiplying all the child entries for each parent and using 2 for anything greater than 2, but keeping the 0 or 1 otherwise. The MySQL for this is a bit beyond my grasp though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler if 0-1-2 were the order because you could use a single min() function. This way you need to tweak the min() function a little bit in the inside to give different weight to number 1 and you need to interpret the results back in the set part with another case expression:

```
update table1,
      (select table1_id, min(case status2 when 1 then 3 else status2 end) as status2
       from table2
       group by table1_id) t2
set table1.status1=case t2.status2 when 3 then 1 else status2 end
where table1.table1_id=t2.table1_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree that the 0, 1, 2 order would be simpler. That's the fun of working with an existing system though.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select t.table1_id, (max((t.status2 + 2) mod 3) + 1) mod 3 as status1
from Table2 t
group by t.table1_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b293/8

Explanation:

We need a function *f(n)* which will convert the numbers (0, 1, 2) the way that *f(2)* is ordered between *f(0)* and *f(1)*. There are several ways to achieve that. For example *f(n) = abs(n - 1.1)* would convert:

```sql
0 -> 1.1
1 -> 0.1
2 -> 0.9
```

This would already work, if we just need to order the result.

```sql
create table t (n int);
insert into t values (0), (1), (2);

select n, abs(n - 1.1)
from t 
order by abs(n - 1.1) desc;

-- 
n   abs(n - 1.1)
0   1,1
2   0,9
1   0,1
```

But if we want to use `MAX` or `MIN` in a `GROUP BY` statement without a subquery, the function must be reversible. So we also need a function *g(m)* with *g(f(n)) = n*. Because we only have 3 values, we can use the modulo function to "rotate" the numbers until we have the needed order.

```sql
select n
  , (n + 1) mod 3 as rotate_1
  , (n + 2) mod 3 as rotate_2
  , (n + 3) mod 3 as rotate_3
from t

--
n rotate_1 rotate_2 rotate_3
0        1        2        0
1        2        0        1
2        0        1        2
```

We see, *f(n) = (n + 2) mod 3* (rotate_2) is the function we need. An we can use `MAX` on that function. To convert it back to the original number we just need to "rotate" once more with 
 *g(m) = (m + 1) mod 3*. The "strongest" number would be *g(MAX(f(n)))*

```sql
select
  (MAX((n + 2) mod 3) + 1) mod 3 as strongest,
  (MIN((n + 2) mod 3) + 1) mod 3 as weakest
from t

-- 
strongest   weakest
        0         1
```

And that can be used in a `GROUP BY` statement to get "strongest" number each item.

Comment: A tricky solution! But it would be even better if you provided some background to the answer, not just code.

Comment: Happy now, @Shadow? :-)